# AS font now too tiny

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts

I upgraded from AS 1.0.0 to 1.2.2 and now the font on my java source files is almost too tiny to read.  Looks like 3 pt type.  Go to settings and see it's set to monospace 12 but it can't be changed.  How can I make it readable?

In case the answer is "I can't make it larger" then how can I go back to AS 1.0.0?

Comment: Have u tried the propper uninstall and inatall again?